# Selenium webdriver not opening new tab in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The code below only opens the first website and does not open a new tab. If I make it go to a new url after the `new_tab` it just send me to a different url in the same tab.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



browser=(r"D:\Developer\Software\Python\chromedriver.exe")
b=webdriver.Chrome(browser)

google=b.get('http://www.google.com')
time.sleep(7)

new_tab=b.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
b.execute_script("window.open('http://newsite.com')")
```

to open URL in new tab

Also note that you have to switch to new tab to be able to handle it:

```
current = b.current_window_handle
b.execute_script("window.open('http://newsite.com')")
new_tab = [tab for tab in b.window_handles if tab != current][0]
b.switch_to.window(new_tab)
```

To get back to main window:

```
b.switch_to.window(current)
```